# Exclude transitive dependency maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I have a project where I need to use a 3rd party library X. X internally has dependency on Y but I don't need Y in my project since it causes some issues.

How can I exclude Y from my project but still internally let X use it.

pomX.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Y</groupId>
      <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
      <version>Y.version</version> 
    </dependency>
```

projectPom.xml

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>X</groupId>
      <artifactId>X</artifactId>
      <version>X.version</version> 
   </dependency>
```

What i tried was this-

ProjectPom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>X</groupId>
      <artifactId>X</artifactId>
      <version>X.version</version> 
     <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>Y</groupId>
              <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

But this causes Y to be not available for X too during the build. How can I exclude Y from my project but still let X use it internally?

Comment: Instead of X and Y, it would be more useful to precise the issues and/or libraries involved? e.g. what do you mean by "but still internally let X use it"?

Comment: This `Y but I don't need Y in my project since it causes some issues.` sounds like a real problem? Do you use Y ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible.

Maven takes the dependencies and constructs classpaths.

If Y is on the classpath, then it is available to all other elements of the classpath, no matter where it originally came from.

You can make distinctions like "I need this at compile time, not at runtime" or vice versa, but you cannot restrict dependency Y to usage by X.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude it as transitive dependency (`exclusion`) and at the same time add it as your own dependency using `provided`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>X</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>X.version</version> 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>Y</groupId>
                <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Y</groupId>
        <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This way `X` will be part of your build result (i.e. when building a `war`-file), but `Y` will not. Still `Y` is available at compile time.

Comment: I do not understand what the exclusion should help here.